# Why is this lookaround regex returning unexpected result?

Tags: python, regex

```
txt = "r/1 /r/2 er/3"
x = re.findall("(?!e)r\/[0-9]", txt)
```

The above code matches `r/1`, `r/2`, `r/3` (i.e everything)

while changing it to `?=e` does not match anything

Isn't the first code supposed to match only `r/1 and r/2` since I am basically saying "match pattern `r/digit` but only if it's not preceded with an `e`"

Comment: What do you mean, it doesn't match anything? [I see three matches.](https://ideone.com/sfOhy0)

Comment: A site I usually use to debug my regular expressions is [this one](https://regex101.com/). It explains each search so its easier to see if the command you are asking for is what you really want it to be.

Comment: @user2357112 Sorry, I mixed them up. Editing now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `(?!e)` is a negative look*ahead* that fails the match if, immediately to the right of the current location, its pattern finds a match. So, `(?!e)r` always matches because `r` is not `e`, and `(?!e)r\/[0-9]` = `r\/[0-9]` (i.e. the lookahead is redundant as it does not impact the matching process).

You want a [negative lookbehind](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), `(?<!e)`:

```
(?<!e)r/[0-9]+
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/d1HscR/1). I also advise to quantify the `[0-9]` pattern to match 1 or more digits.

**Details**

- `(?<!e)` - a negative lookbehind that makes sure there is no `e` immediately to the left of the current location
- `r/` - a `r/` substring
- `[0-9]+` - 1+ digits.

Comment: thanks! But then can you explain what my current regex means? That `e` is not expected after `r`?

Comment: @looneyGod `(?=e)r` means that a character has to be equal to 'e' and 'r' at the same time (and thus never matches). `(?!e)r` means that the character needs to be equal to 'r' and not equal to 'e' (so it's the same as just writing `r`).

Comment: The `(?!e)` is a negative loo*ahead* that fails the match if, immediately to the right of the current location, its pattern finds a match. So, `(?!e)r` always matches because `r` is not `e`.